# Finding two vertices of a rectangle given two vertices and angle?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a rectangle where I know the coordinates of the opposite diagonal corners.
I also know the angle that the rectangle is rotated.
I would like to solve to find the coordinates of the other two vertices or opposite corners.

To help illustrate I am posting a diagram I found on here.

Basically I would like to find point C and D. And I know that the rectangle ABCD is rotated to the left by 23 degrees.

[image: Diagram]

How can I solve for C and D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different approaches.

If you're comfortable using matrices to perform rotations of points in a plane,
take the rotation matrix
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta &\sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta& \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$$
where $\theta$ is equivalent to $23$ degrees, 
and apply it to the coordinates of $A$ and $B$.
This is a $23$-degree rotation to the right,
making the images of the four points into a rectangle aligned with the axes.
You can then easily find the coordinates of the images of $C$ and $D$,
and invert the rotation (apply the matrix $A^T$) to find the points $C$ and $D$.

Without using transformations, you know that the slope of line $AD$ is 
$\tan \theta$ (where $\theta$ is equivalent to $23$ degrees)
and the slope of the line $BD$ is $-\frac{1}{\tan\theta}$.
You can derive equations for the lines $AD$ and $BD$ from these facts
and the coordinates of $A$ and $B$.
Solve these equations simultaneously and you have the coordinates of $D$.
A similar procedure finds the coordinates of $C$.

Comment: Thanks both answers helped. Although I know of them, I don't have much practice with matrices.

Answer (score 0):

With your angle you can find the line $ax+b$ from $A$ to $D$.
now take a line $a^{-1}x+c$ through B and find the intersection of these lines. This is the point $D$.